# Was there ever a cable channel called The Puppy Channel which broadcast for three years?

Tags: united-states, television

Ages ago, I heard about something called "The Puppy Channel" - a channel in the United States that broadcast nothing but puppies.

On Reddit's TIL (Today I Learned), there's a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/1wnof0/til_there_was_a_cable_network_called_the_puppy/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), with over 3000 upvotes, saying

> TIL there was a cable network called The Puppy Channel. All it did for three years was broadcast footage of puppies playing. ([en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Puppy_Channel))

Was there a cable channel called The Puppy Channel which broadcast for three years footage purely of puppies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this episode](https://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/233/starting-from-scratch?act=1) of This American Life, [Dan FitzSimons](https://www.linkedin.com/in/dan-fitzsimons-b8aa6a14) started the Puppy Channel in June 1996, and worked on the concept for 5 years. Unfortunately, no cable distributor bought the show.

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article has since been [deleted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/The_Puppy_Channel), with one user citing [Puppy Channel Is Dog Tired](http://www.broadcastingcable.com/news/news-articles/puppy-channel-dog-tired/106392), written in 2005, suggesting that the channel never existed:

> Last week, an e-mail promoting the Puppy Channel rained down on nearly
>   every member of the Broadcasting & Cable staff and, we suspect, on
>   many, many others in the media.
>
> The e-mail’s sketchy wording—the “big dogs” that attend the NCTA
>   convention this week “may have indicated the channel’s time might have
>   arrived”—reminded us that we’ve been hearing for nearly a decade about
>   the imminent launch of this channel devoted to the pairing of lovable
>   pups and nice music.
>
> Dogs may be man’s best friend, but journalists can be a puppy’s
>   faithful companion. A sampling ...

[Introducing The Puppy Channel: The Greatest Invention of the 1990s](https://redditblog.com/2015/10/03/the-puppy-channel-fitzsimons/), written in October 2015, says it was never successful:

> Unfortunately, The Puppy Channel never became its own cable network,
>   and the pilot [tv show] stopped airing sometime around the start of the new
>   millennium.